# Boats, Trouble with code

Tags: java, oop

I have a bit trouble with my code. What I want is to use the if statement to compare the amount of masts the ships have. To put it in code I want this.

```
if (minimumAantalMasten > aantalMasten ) {
    System.out.println(boot.toString());}
}
```

But I can not access this variable. I tried using getters and setters but it does not work since I cannot access these either...

Here is my full code:

```
ArrayList<Boot> boten = new ArrayList<>();

boten.add(new Boot("Berenboot", new Schipper("Kapitein Brom", "GVB III",37501), 2,4));
boten.add(new Boot("Kon-Tiki", null, 1, 6));
boten.add(new Boot("Titanic", new Schipper("Edward John Smith", "GVB III", 13), 423, 1912));
boten.add(new ZeilBoot(3, 297, "Oosterschelde", new Schipper("Roy Heiner", "GVB II", 9617), 9, 24));
boten.add(new ZeilBoot(3, 197, "De Brederode", new Schipper("Maarten Harpertszoon Tromp", null, 2341598), 4,270));
boten.add(new ZeilBoot(1, 27, "Cato", new Schipper("Niels Trommel", "VB II", 158), 2, 4));
boten.add(new ZeilBoot(1, 16, "Golden Star", new Schipper("Marit Bouwmeester", null, 5), 0, 4));
boten.add(new MotorBoot(35, "Strider", new Schipper("Rene de Vogel", "VB II",853), 4, 8));
boten.add(new MotorBoot(21, "Supprise VII", new Schipper("Pete Black", "PNB IV", 13), 4, 8));
boten.add(new MotorBoot(286, "Spirit of Australia", null, 0, 0));

public static void laatBotenMetMinimumAantalMastenZien(ArrayList<Boot> boten, int minimumAantalMasten) {
    System.out.println("\n=== Boten met minimum aantal aan masten ===");
    for (Boot boot : boten) {
        if (minimumAantalMasten > aantalMasten) {
            System.out.println(boot.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the class with the variable i try to access:

```
public class ZeilBoot extends Boot {

private int aantalMasten;
private int zeilOppervlakPerMast;

public ZeilBoot(int aantalMasten, int zeilOppervlakPerMast, String naam, Schipper schipper, int aantalHutten, int aantalSlaapplaatsen) {
    super(naam, schipper, aantalHutten, aantalSlaapplaatsen);
    this.aantalMasten = aantalMasten;
    this.zeilOppervlakPerMast = zeilOppervlakPerMast;
}

@Override
public boolean isVaarbewijsNodig() {
    return ((super.isVaarbewijsNodig()) || (zeilOppervlakPerMast > 150));
}

/**
 * @return the aantalMasten
 */
public int getAantalMasten() {
    return aantalMasten;
}

/**
 * @param aantalMasten the aantalMasten to set
 */
public void setAantalMasten(int aantalMasten) {
    this.aantalMasten = aantalMasten;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return super.toString() + "Aantal Masten: " + aantalMasten + "\n" + "Zeiloppervlak per mast: "
            + zeilOppervlakPerMast + "\n";
}

}
```

Comment: Do `minimumAantalMasten > boot.getAantalMasten()`

Comment: Please give a [mcve], even if the variable names are still not in English it's at least then clear what the problem is.

Comment: Are you expecting your method to print the boats that aren't sailboats?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @AndrewLi i tried that and that does not work. I get this error: error: cannot find symbol
            if (minimumAantalMasten > boot.getAantalMasten() ) {
  symbol:   method getAantalMasten()
  location: variable boot of type Boot
1 error

Comment: @DavidWallace No actually the other way around. I am trying to print sailboats with at least the minimal amount of masts that is given as parameter

Comment: In that case, you have your `>` the wrong way.  It should be `minimumAantalMasten <= aantalMasten`.  In particular, if you're going to use the second snippet in Lisa's solution, you'll need to change it to `if (minimumAantalMasten <= ((ZeilBoot) boot).getAantalMasten())`.  An alternative solution would be to implement `getAantalMasten` in the `Boot` class as well as the `ZeilBoot` class.  The version in `Boot` could simply return 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method should be:

```
public static void laatBotenMetMinimumAantalMastenZien(ArrayList<Boot> boten, int minimumAantalMasten) {
    System.out.println("\n=== Boten met minimum aantal aan masten ===");
    for (Boot boot : boten) {
        if (minimumAantalMasten > boot.getAantalMasten()) {
            System.out.println(boot.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

If `aantalMasten` is a field only in `ZeilBoot`, then you have to check instance type and cast:

```
for (Boot boot : boten) {
    if (boot instanceof ZeilBoot) {
        if (minimumAantalMasten > ((ZeilBoot) boot).getAantalMasten()) {
            System.out.println(boot.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Lisa's excellent solution.

In the `Boot` class, add this method.

```
public int getAantalMasten() {
    return 0;
}
```

This will be overridden in the `ZeilBoot` class.

```
@Override
public int getAantalMasten() {
    return aantalMasten;
}
```

Then you can rely on polymorphism to ensure the right version of the method is called.

```
for (Boot boot : boten) {
    if (minimumAantalMasten <= boot.getAantalMasten()) {
        System.out.println(boot);
    }
}
```

Note that there's no need to explicitly call `toString` inside the parentheses after `println`, because the `println` method will call it for you.  I've also changed your `>` to `<=` since you stated in comments that you wanted to print a boat whose number of masts was *greater than* the specified minimum.